# Prevent Twig from injecting error message

Tags: symfony, twig

I followed this tutorial http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/controller/error_pages.html to customize twig 404 error page, I created the file "app/Resources/TwigBundle/views/Exception/error404.html.twig".

It shows up as expected, the only problem is that, I have a message injected automatically at the the closing html tag :

```
Not Found
The request URL /app.php/register was not found on this server.
```

I noticed that it was injected whenever my page contains the closing body tag and I can't get rid of it.

**EDIT:**

I found the solution, I was using Monolog, and activated another handler not the best way, which made the confusion and printed the error twice.

Answer (score 0):

In httpd.conf file you need to remove #

```
#LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

after removing # line will look like this:

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

.

Comment: My problem is not the content of the error, I threw a NotFoundHttpException in the register Controller, my problem, is that I don't want to have the message added below, by the way, the mod_rewrite is working well

Comment: The leading slash could be causing your problem.

Change

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
to

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [L]

Comment: Problem is, if I remove my testing exception and call the same url (/app.php/register), everything works fine